# NoSQL duplicate data or new document

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql

I'm messing around with MongoDB and I'm wondering what is the best solution : I have a collection Animal and each animal have a name and a type.

But for front-end needs each type has a color.

So there are two possibilities :

First one :

```
Animal
  .animal 1
    name: Simba
    race: lion
    type:
        name: felin
        color: blue
  .animal 2
    name: Franck
    race: turtle
    type:
        name: turtle
        color: red
  .animal 3
    name: Francis
    race: turtle
    type:
        name: turtle
        color: red
```

Second :

```
Animal
  .animal 1
    name: Simba
    race: lion
    type: (id of type collection)
Type
  .type 1
    name: felin
    color: blue
  .type 2
    name: turtle
    color: red
```

So, should I duplicate data ? Or should I create a new collection ?

Thank you for you time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach is better if your `type` document is not going to change so often and is only limited to 2-3 attributes inside it.

However, if you plan to add more attributes in the `type` document then you should consider creating a new collection and store the `type-id` in the `animals` collection.

Also, if your `type` document is going to change frequently in future, you would not like to update each record in `animals` who has that `type` in it, instead you would like to change it only at 1 place (`type` collection).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first approach as the type key has only 2 sub-keys. I prefer new collection when I have more number of keys as it involves DB operation.